# Crystal reports exception: "The Report Application Server failed"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, xcelsius

I'm running the following code:

```
ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
crystalReport.Load(reportPath);
DataTable dtReportData;
DbUtils.GetSqlResult(dataQuery, out dtReportData);
crystalReport.SetDataSource(dtReportData);

var crDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
var crFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
crDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = pdfFilePath;
crystalReport.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = PaperOrientation.Landscape;

var crExportOptions = crystalReport.ExportOptions;
{
    crExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
    crExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
    crExportOptions.DestinationOptions = crDiskFileDestinationOptions;
    crExportOptions.FormatOptions = crFormatTypeOptions;
}

crystalReport.Export(); //PROGRAM FAILS HERE WHEN THE DATATABLE CONTAINS 900 OR MORE ROWS
crystalReport.Close();
```

And it fails when trying to export to pdf a report that has as datasource a table that has more than 900 rows. The exception is:

> The Report Application Server failed

And the stacktrace is:

> at
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ConvertDotNetToErom.ThrowDotNetException(Exception
>   e)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext
>   reqContext)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext
>   reqContext)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.Export(ExportRequestContext
>   reqContext)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.Export()    at
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Export()

Any idea how to approach this problem?

***UPDATE***

When using Crystal Reports Viewer, I can export the report to PDF while doing the same action from the Crystal Reports Designer is resulting in an error. Is there a way programatically to use the viewer's libraries when exporting a crystal reports object?